# Can i run Apache kafka in Apache Tomcat container . If yes how?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have seen the tutorail of setting up solr in tomcat  . I am curious to know if it is possible to run apache kafka in tomcat container . if yes how can i do that .

Answer (score 1):

For kafka its not possible. In case of solr its distribution comes with solr.war which runs on default jetty container, so that solr calls are exposed as rest service. You can deploy solr.war on tomcat as well with few configurations and running in tomcat acting as servlet container and can expose solr rest calls. In kafka distribution there is no such possibility.

Answer (score 0):

kafka requires a running zookeeper server (which is bundled with the kafka server). Zookeeper runs as a separate service...no tomcat (or any other servlet container or JavaEE application server required).

Please read the "Quickstart" guide on the kafka website: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
It tells you exactly how to get started.